How to recover missing objects in blender
I was working on a project on my Laptop with some objects imported from installed library. When I'm trying to move the project into my pc for rendering the objects form the library looks missing

Having that library installed is there any way to recover these objects with the same position and scale?

Method 1

File > External Data > Find Missing Files


It might be useful to enable "Find All" in options while browsing, if there are multiple libraries in the same folder or subfolders:


Choose the folder containing all library blend files.


Method 2

Outliner > Display Mode



Data API



Change the Library file path


Save the file and restart blender,
The object that using that library will change.

Method 3
Scripting for batch operation
import bpy

for datablock in bpy.data.libraries:
    print(datablock.filepath)

    datablock.filepath = '..'

# Save the file and restart blender manually


It works! Thank you so much.
